# Route53に設定しているドメインからアクセスできなくなってしまいました。

Tags: amazon-route53

現在AWS S3(以下AWSを省略)の静的ホスティングを使用してCloudFront経由で配信しているVue.jsのアプリケーションがありまして、Route53に登録したドメインからアクセスできるようにしていたのですが、お昼頃からRoute53に登録したドメインからアクセスできなくなってしまいました。
ブラウザからアクセスすると以下のように表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Route53に登録したドメインはこちらで
https://smart-kitchen.website
CloudFrontのドメインはこちらになります。
https://d1gahpd5mshou8.cloudfront.net
CloudFrontからはアクセス可能です。

nslookupコマンドを実行してみたのですが名前解決できていないようです。

```
****@MacBook-Pro smart-kitchen-client % nslookup smart-kitchen.website
Server:     2001:a7ff:5f01::a
Address:    2001:a7ff:5f01::a#53

** server can't find smart-kitchen.website: NXDOMAIN
```

Route53のレコードを一度削除して再度登録してみたのですが変化はなくてどうすればいいか分からずアドバイスを頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

[Whois検索情報](https://tech-unlimited.com/whois.html)でドメインの状況を確認してみると

> Domain Status: clientHold https://icann.org/epp#clientHold

と表示されています。
これは何らかの理由でリジストラからドメインが停止されていると表示される状態です。
詳しくは[AWSのドキュメント](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-domain-suspended.html)を確認していただきたいですが、

支払いが滞ったり、メールなどの認証が足りなかったり、必要な書類を提出していないと
取られる一般的な処置です。
Route53でステータスを確認するか、もしくはドメインに設定しているメールアドレス宛にAWSからメールが届いているはずです。そちらで確認して何らかの対処をする必要があるでしょう。
それでもわからない場合はAWSにサポートをお願いするしかないと思います。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。
ドメインを購入したときに登録したメールアドレス宛に、メールアドレスの確認ができなかったためドメインが停止されたという旨のメールが届いていました。
確認メールを再度送信して確認を行ったところ、smart-kitchen.websiteのドメインからアクセスすることが出来るようになりました。